# How to retrieve an element within several tags by tag name for selenium automated testing

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

I'm creating an automated selenium test using org.openqa.selenium.By to grab certain elements on the webpage that is loaded but I get nothing back when I'm searching for some elements.  This is probably because the element I'm searching for is within several HTML tags? I put this code in the browser console just to see if I could see the tag I'm looking for listed but I only get back a list of top level element tags.

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     console.log(all.item(i))
}
```

Would anyone know of a better way to get an element using selenium since just By.tagname(tagname) doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the page you are trying to automate? It's hard to tell what is wrong with your code without any reference to the HTML on the page. There are different locator strategies such as classname, xpath, and css selector, but we can't suggest anything without some HTML to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example to get tag from HTML

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium");
     List<WebElement> stack = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
     for (WebElement element:stack) {
         System.out.println("Name of the attribute is:- " + element.getAttribute("class"));
     }
     driver.close();
```